# angularjs: multiple values in a ng-switch-when

Tags: angularjs, ng-switch

I have the following ngSwitch:

```
<p ng-switch="status">
    <span ng-switch-when="wrong|incorrect">
       Wrong
    </span>
    <span ng-switch-default>
       Correct
    </span>
</p>
```

As you can see, I have the text `Wrong` for two options `wrong` and `correct`. I have tried (as you can see) to use the pipe `|`, but that doesn't work. Any suggestions ?

Comment: can you explain the logic of your switch statement, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to show the text `wrong` if the variable `status` contains the value `wrong` or `incorrect`. For all other values it should show the text `Correct`

Answer (score 76, accepted):

For angular >=v1.5.10,

You can do it by adding `ng-switch-when-separator="|"` to `ng-switch-when` node.
[see example in documentation.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)

```
<span ng-switch-when="wrong|incorrect" ng-switch-when-separator="|">
```

see discussion here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3410
Note, based on my experience it doesn't work with numbers...yet?

Comment: Despite the documentation reading otherwise, this functionality isn't yet in v1.5.8, but will get into 1.5.9 onwards (see: https://github.com/flyfly6/angular.js/pull/1).

Answer (score 43):

This is almost same with using a ng-if, but the advantage of this is that you can use ng-switch-when="true" or default or false multiple times within main ng-switch.

```
<p ng-switch on="(status == 'wrong') || (status == 'incorrect')">
    <span ng-switch-when="true">
        Wrong
    </span>
    <span ng-switch-default>
       Correct
    </span>
</p>
```

Live : http://jsfiddle.net/8yf15t2d/

Comment: Your answer should contain an explanation of your code and a description how it solves the problem.

Comment: What is the advantage over "ng-if" ?

Comment: If there are many switch cases then there is a performance benefit, as ng-if sets up a watcher for each ng-if, while ng-switch only sets up one watcher. This is most relevant if you're inside a ng-repeat, as then all these watchers would add up.

Answer (score 20):

You can't have multiple conditions with a single `ng-switch-when`.

One alternative is to use an `ng-if`, but in the case of error handling, I prefer to populate an error variable on the scope in the controller, and use `ng-show=error`.

Answer (score 16):

You can add a filter to the `status` that maps values that mean the same thing into the same value.

```
.filter('meaning', function() {
    return function(input) {
      input = input || '';
      if (['wrong', 'amiss','awry', 'bad', 'erroneous', 'false', 'inaccurate',\
           'misguided', 'mistaken', 'unsound', 'incorrect'].indexOf(input) != -1)
          return 'wrong';
      // You can make it generic like this:
      synonymsDictionary = {
        'someWord' : ['syn1', 'syn2', 'syn3' ... ],
        'someOtherWord' : ['otherWordSyn1', 'otherWordSyn2', 'otherWordSyn3' ...]
        .
        .
        .
      };

      for (var word in synonymsDictionary)
          if (synonymsDictionary[word].indexOf(input) != -1)
              return word; // This way you could iterate over a bunch of arrays...

         // Edge case
         else return input;
    };
  })
```

Then you simply

```
<p ng-switch="status|meaning">
    <span ng-switch-when="wrong">
       Wrong
    </span>
    <span ng-switch-default>
       Correct
    </span>
</p>
```

Although in your case, you may have just wanted to print a message so you could have pulled the message from a dictionary...

Something like:

```
<span ng-if="status">
    {{getStatusMessage(status)}}
</span>
```

Comment: very nice and under-rated

Answer (score 5):

This cannot be achieved with angular's base directives, but if you like, you could write your own directive to implement this, and could already interface with the existing ngSwitch directive.

ngSwitchController has one property `cases` which is a map. Every case key is prefixed with an `!` and the default case is equal to `?`. Each case value is an object with two properties: `transclude` and `element`.
*Warning*: Unlike [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController), ngSwitchController is **not** published API, so it's subject to change.

Based off of the original ngSwitchWhenDirective, we can construct a multiswitchWhen, that will work with all existing ngSwitch, ngSwitchWhen, and ngSwitchDefault directives without conflict.

```
.directive('multiswitchWhen', function () {
    return {
        transclude: 'element',
        priority: 800,
        require: '^ngSwitch',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, $transclude) {
            var selectTransclude = { transclude: $transclude, element: element };
            angular.forEach(attrs.multiswitchWhen.split('|'), function(switchWhen) {
                ctrl.cases['!' + switchWhen] = (ctrl.cases['!' + switchWhen] || []);
                ctrl.cases['!' + switchWhen].push(selectTransclude);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Example plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/K9znnnFiVnKAgGccSlrQ?p=preview

Comment: Excellent solution!. It Should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can add another switch case.

**Example:**

```
<p ng-switch="status">
    <span ng-switch-when="wrong">
       Wrong
    </span>
<span ng-switch-when="incorrect">
       Wrong
    </span>
    <span ng-switch-default>
       Correct
    </span>
</p>
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/choroshin/Zt2qE/2/

Comment: This is correct, but it's not answering the question.

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: multiple values in a ng-switch-**when** not just ng-switch

Comment: But why would you want multiple values in ng-switch-when? Why can't that be achieved using another ng-switch-when? I guess DRY reasons?

Answer (score 0):

### ng-switch with option selection may help

```
<select ng-model="myVar">
  <option value="option1">Option 1
  <option value="option2">Option 2
  <option value="option3">Option 3
</select>
<div ng-switch="myVar">
  <div ng-switch-when="option1">
     <p>Option 1 is selected .</p>
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-when="option1">
     <p>Option 2 is selected</p>
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-default>
     <p>Option 3 is selected </p>
  </div>
</div>
```